# Split WAR on two parts: code and dependencies

Tags: maven, build, dependencies, war, build-dependencies

I have very big WAR file. And currently my internet connection is weak. Uploading of the WAR on my server after little changes takes too much time. I want to optimize the process. I would like to split WAR so, that dependencies will be contained in one part (probably, JAR) and the code in another (WAR). That way I will be able to upload both parts once, and then after changes in the code, I will need to re-upload only code part. Is it possible?

PS: I suspect, it may be possible using Tomcat's /lib folder, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What I understand is this: you want to create one war and one jar, and both artifacts belong to the same web application. You want to deploy them to the same application context in `webapps`. Is this correct?

Comment: @JimHawkins yes, it's correct. Jar should contain all dependencies needed for war. It will allow me to have a lightweight war. Do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: This was my first thought: create a maven multi module project, one module for each jar and war. But I'm not sure how to achieve the goal that both artifacts are deployed separately to the same application context

Comment: That will simply not work, cause the jar should be packaged into the war otherwise it will not work nor the deployment will not work either....

Comment: @khmarbaise What about Tomcat's /lib directory? Seems like it is intended to keep dependencies.

Comment: The lib folder of Tomcat is for packages which should be for all deployed WAR's in Tomcat which introduces so called `shared libraries` which is something you should prevent cause it will become hard to maintain and to deploy. So best is to have all-in-one which means simply having all deps in the war file which can simply deployed. Makes installation and updates simpler (simply install tomcat and deploy your war file)...